# case-insensitive queries for a Socrata SoQL

Tags: reactjs, api, socrata

I trying to find all the mixed case results.

For example 'Abee' will only return is searching that exact case.

I've looked in the [like '...'](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/functions/like.html) option and tried upper (but it appears to be for the return not the query).

This is working query I'm passing.

https://data.nasa.gov/resource/gh4g-9sfh.json?$where=name%20like%20%27%25Abee%25%27

In my React app this is the function:

#### App.js

```
onChangeSearch = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    const name = e.target.elements.name.value;
    console.log('name: '+ name);
    const url = `${API_URL}?$limit=${API_LIMIT}&$where=name like %27%25${name}%25%27`;
    this.getData(url, 'meteorite');
  }
```

#### Form.js

```
const Form = props => (
    <form onSubmit={props.onChangeSearch}>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..." />
        <button>Search</button>
    </form>
);
```

I would the query itself to setup regardless if the user inputs 'ABEE', 'abee', or 'aBee'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

https://data.nasa.gov/resource/gh4g-9sfh.json?$limit=100&$where=upper(name)=%27ABEE%27

The documentation included an example that wasn't that clear:

[upper(...)](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/functions/upper.html)

`You can also use it within the $where parameter to do case-insensitive matches`

Answer (score 1):

First make your query uppercase

`const nameUpper = name.toUpperCase();`

Then use `upper()` on the name parameter, so the search is performed on the name properties while they are uppercase.

```
    const name = e.target.elements.name.value.toUpperCase();

    const url = `${API_URL}?$limit=${API_LIMIT}&$where=upper(name) like%27%25${name}%25%27`;
```